# Backward compatibility of ewmvar in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

It seems that the `ewmvar` is not always backward compatible. When using the settings `bias=True` in both pandas 0.14.1 and 0.15.2, we obtain the same result. However, when `bias=False`, as is the default, the results are no longer the same.

Is there a way to stay compatible in this case? I would like to make sure that it does.

```
s = Series(range(1, 11))
ewmvar(s, span=19, bias=False)
```

Gives in pandas 0.14.1:

```
0   -2.343804e-16
1    2.631579e-01
2    6.998135e-01
3    1.307082e+00
4    2.080978e+00
5    3.016467e+00
6    4.107530e+00
7    5.347237e+00  
8    6.727838e+00
9    8.240851e+00
```

However in pandas 0.15.2:

```
0         NaN
1    0.500000
2    0.998155
3    1.658692
4    2.477992
5    3.451425
6    4.573407
7    5.837471
8    7.236344
9    8.762037
```

Thank you for any insights. The alternative is I set up my own ewmvar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see the section on ewma changes here (a little ways down): http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew.html#new-features

These were mostly bug fixes and inconsistencies. Any actual changes are explained and the rationale. I believe backwards compat was preserved if it was not a buggy case (iirc was you are showing was an incorrect calculation)